# How to create working HTML tags in textfields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to add HTML tags when creating posts and i want them to be converted to a normal text for the user.
I want to know how to add links in posts for users to access them directly when they click on it. Any help with Django or Flask is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? Something like this, is for Django/Html

```
<a href="{% url 'app_name:urls_path_name' %}">Here is a Link</a>
```

Comment: No please. I am developing a blog and i want to add links and HTML tags in the user interface when creating posts. Like how WordPress allows you to view your code in HTML when you want to add links. Here is a link to a visual of my case https://www.facebook.com/groups/websworld/permalink/2141920562571690/?app=fbl

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys
CkEditor did it
Just pip install django-ckeditor and read the docs